# replace() concat() and substr() add character at specific location in string cannot get the position right

Tags: mysql, sql

**End result:** all 3 fields should be merged (solved OK), and the character "T" should be added as the 5th character in the merged string (no other characters should be removed or altered in sequence). (see all specifics below).

What am I doing wrong?

**Data is in the following format:**

**data1:** `AL`

**data2:** `33 0230S 0440E`

**data3:** `SW`

**Here is my current sql:**

```
replace(concat(b.data1,
      substr(b.data2, 4, 1),
        'T',
      substr(b.data2, 1),
   b.data3), ' ', '')
AS MergedData
```

**The final output should look like:**

```
AL33T0230S0440ESW
```

I've been able to get the "T" placed at random locations, but cannot get it consistently added as the 5th character from the start of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- replace *only* on data2 (because that's the only field that needs it), then
- concat() to join it all up, and finally
- the [insert()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) function to insert the `T`

(Don't use substr at all)

```
insert(concat(data1, replace(data2, ' ', ''), data3), 5, 0, 'T')
```

Here's a test:

```
set @data1 := 'AL', @data2 := '33 0230S 0440E', @data3 := 'SW';

select
    insert(concat(@data1, replace(@data2, ' ', ''), @data3), 5, 0, 'T')
    as MergedData;
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+
| MergedData        |
+-------------------+
| AL33T0230S0440ESW |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Random locations seems odd, this seems to work though;

```
replace(concat(b.data1,
    substr(b.data2, 1, 2),
    'T',
    substr(b.data2, 4),
    b.data3), ' ', '')
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30af3/3).

Answer (score 0):

Find the position of the first space in `data2`, replace it with `T`, remove the rest of the spaces in the resulting string, then concatenate it with the two other values:

```
CONCAT(
    b.data1,
    REPLACE(INSERT(b.data2, LOCATE(' ', b.data2), 1, 'T'), ' ', ''),
    b.data3
) AS MergedData
```